# How to resolve two consecutive slashed with the REST API URL?

Tags: java, rest-assured

We have started automation for our API's but we found one issue. During testing found that Rest assured not able to handle two consecutive slashed with the API URL. I put lots of effort to investigate and resolve it but no luck yet.

The issue is mentioned here :
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/867

```
response = SerenityRest.given()
                .headers(headers.getHeaders("x-api-key", "1234"))
                .get("https://www.test.com//apis/Customers/customerId");
```

I have also tried to disable URL encoding with the help of `.urlEncodingEnabled()` but still facing the same issue. Can someone please help me out to resolve my issue?

In my case two consecutive slashes are present:  `//`apis/Customers/customerId

Comment: If the issue is still open, there's little you can do beside waiting for it to be solved (and fixing your client in the meantime so it doesn't send double slashes, if possible)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  can you please let me know how i can solve this ?

Comment: No, I can't, because I'm not familiar with the internals of rest-assured. You have to wait for someone to fix the bug you linked. Or solve it yourself. It's a bug in their code, not in yours.

Comment: Yes I know that i am just looking for workaround if exist?

Comment: If you remove double slash. .Does it give result? - https://www.test.com/apis/Customers/customerId

Comment: If yes, then you can set BaseURI like this -                             RestAssured.baseURI = "https://www.test.com";
RestAssured.basePath = "/apis/Customers/{customerId}";
RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();

Comment: no it's not working if we remove  double slash